# Calculating expected value of profit of selling a product with demand distributed normally in newsvendor model

Tags: normal-distribution

I started recently learning the **newsvendor model**, where **V** is the sell price, **c** is the purchase cost, **h** is the overage cost, **π** is the underage cost, **Q** is the quantity stocked, **D** is the demand for the product,

$ P(Q,D) =
\begin{cases}
(V-c)*Q-π(d-Q),  & \text{d>Q} \\
V*d-c*Q+h(Q-d), & \text{d$\leq$Q}
\end{cases}$

is the profit function,

$E(P(Q,D))=\int_0^\infty P(Q,D)*f_D(d) \,dd=\int_0^Q ((V-c)*Q-π(d-Q))*f_D(d) \,dd+\int_Q^\infty (V*d-c*Q+h(Q-d))*f_D(d) \,dd$

is the profit expectancy

Now,If D is distributed normally **($D \sim \mathcal{N}(μ,σ^2)$)** and the optimal quantity of the product-$Q^*$ is known, **how do I find the profit expectancy-E(P(Q,D))**, solving the both integrals ( $\int_0^Q ((V-c)*Q-π(d-Q))*f_D(d) \,dd$ and $\int_Q^\infty (V*d-c*Q+h(Q-d))*f_D(d) \,dd)$ )?

I've looked it up in a lot of sources, and couldn't find a proper answer.
Would appreciate any help.

Comment: Hi, Could you please elaborate on how you got those expressions? Thanks

Comment: Actually I left out a factor of $1/2$ in the exponent of $f_X(x)$ (replacing $d$ with $x$) so the first integral is $$\frac{\sigma  \left(\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi }} p \sigma  \left(e^{-\frac{(Q-\mu )^2}{2 \sigma ^2}}-e^{-\frac{\mu ^2}{2 \sigma ^2}}\right)-\left(\text{erf}\left(\frac{\mu }{\sqrt{2} \sigma }\right)+\text{erf}\left(\frac{Q-\mu }{\sqrt{2} \sigma }\right)\right) (c Q+\mu  p-Q (p+V))\right)}{2 \sqrt{\sigma ^2}}.$$

Comment: And the second integral: $$\frac{\sigma  \text{erf}\left(\frac{Q-\mu }{\sqrt{2} \sigma }\right) (c Q+h (\mu -Q)-\mu  V)+\frac{-c Q+h (Q-\mu )+\mu  V}{\sqrt{\frac{1}{\sigma ^2}}}+\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi }} \sigma ^2 (V-h) e^{-\frac{(Q-\mu )^2}{2 \sigma ^2}}}{2 \sqrt{\sigma ^2}}.$$

Comment: As for how I got these, I entered the integrals into Mathematica. You could do the same with Wolfram Alpha or another CAS. It may be possible to compute them by hand, but as you can see the process would be very tedious.

Comment: Since $\ h(Q-d)\ $ is a *cost* when $\ d\le Q\ $, shouldn't the expression for the profit be
$$
Vd-cQ\color{red}{-}h(Q-d)
$$
in this case?

Comment: Also, in the expression for expected profit, you appear to have truncated the normal distribution at $\ D=0\ $.  While this makes sense, it is then *not* true that $\ D\sim\cal{N}\left(\mu, \sigma^2\right) \ $, and the density $\ f_D\ $ would have to be given by
$$
f_D(d)=\cases{0& for $\ d<0\ $\\
              \frac{e^{-\frac{(d-\mu)^2}{\sigma^2}}}{\int_\limits{0}^\infty e^{-\frac{(d-\mu)^2}{\sigma^2}}dd}& for $\ d\ge0\ $}\ ,
$$
rather than the usual expression for an untruncated normal density?

Comment: And don't the integrands of $\ \int_\limits{0}^{\,\,Q}\ $ and $\ \int _\limits{Q}^{\,\,\infty}\ $ in the expression for expected profit need to be switched.